# Click handler not working for <div> with <object> as child

Tags: javascript, svg

I have just two elements, a `div` with an `object` attached as child, which contains an SVG image. The click handler works fine when there is just the `div` by itself, or another tag as it's child, such as `img`. However, when the `object` is a child, the `div` click handler is only triggered in the very bottom right corner. I'm really stuck as to what would be causing this behavior.

```
let divContainer = document.createElement('div');
divContainer.className = 'divContainer';
divContainer.style.position = 'absolute'
divContainer.style.top = '100px';
divContainer.style.width = '150px';
divContainer.style.height = '150px';
divContainer.style.background = 'green';
  
let imageChild = document.createElement('object');
imageChild.type = 'image/svg+xml';
imageChild.data = 'https://svgsilh.com/svg_v2/48363.svg'
imageChild.className = 'imageChild';
imageChild.style.width = 'inherit';
   
document.body.append(divContainer);
// Comment this out, and it works fine
divContainer.append(imageChild);

divContainer.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log('Click OK!');
}
```

Comment: You pig is on top of the container; disable clicks on the pig with: ``imageChild.style.pointerEvents="none";``

Comment: Did you mean to write "pig"? @Danny'365CSI'Engelman?

Comment: The `<object>` is swallowing all the click events. You will have to disable pointer events as @Danny'365CSI'Engelman suggests.

Comment: Sorry for the "you pig".. English is not my native language; and in the Dutch language _you_ and _your_ can be similar spelling..

Comment: Ah hahah, no problems - it's pretty funny now you point it out!! I just read it as 'your' anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code

```
  let divContainer = document.createElement('div');
  divContainer.className = 'divContainer';
  divContainer.style.top = '100px';
  divContainer.style.width = '150px';
  divContainer.style.height = '150px';
  divContainer.style.background = 'green';

  let imageChild = document.createElement('object');
  imageChild.type = 'image/svg+xml';
  imageChild.data = 'https://svgsilh.com/svg_v2/48363.svg';
  imageChild.className = 'imageChild';
  imageChild.style.width = 'inherit';
  imageChild.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

  document.body.append(divContainer);
  // Comment this out, and it works fine
  divContainer.append(imageChild);

  divContainer.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('Click OK!');
  });
```